# Nesting Three.JS renderer in a canvas or div

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I am trying to nest a 3d model viewer in a responsive layout with other information like text. I was using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight but then I switched to .clientWidth and .clientHeight so the renderer size would be controlled by the css but it will not render.

I was using this website for help https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/three-by-css/three-by-css.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>threejs - basic</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0; 
   overflow: hidden; 

  }

  canvas{
   display: inline-block;
   background: red;
   width: 40%;
   height: 40%;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>


<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas>
         <p>hi</p>
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.js"></script>

<script >
 var renderer, 
  scene,
  camera,
  myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');


 //Renderer 
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: myCanvas, antialias: true});
 renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, window.clientHeight);



 //Camera
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, canvas.clientWidth / window.clientHeight, .01, 3000);
 //Scene
 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 //Lights
 var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
 scene.add(light); 

 var light2= new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
 scene.add(light2);

   var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100);



 //Geometry Material 

 var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xF3FFE2});
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 mesh.position.z = -1000;

 scene.add(mesh);

//RenderLoop
 render();
 var delta = 0;
 function render(){
 //RotateMeshes
  mesh.rotation.x += .0001
  mesh.rotation.y += .001
  mesh.rotation.z += .001
 //ActiveVertices
  delta += 0.1;
  geometry.vertices[0].x = -25 + Math.sin(delta) * 50;
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

 };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want `canvas.clientWidth`

Comment: @BenWest still won't work?

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues:

1. Please don't use the same id for multilple elements if you want to create multiple canvas with the same render you can use a class and use a loop to trigger the function to render each canvas.
2. The `clientWith` is for nodes that you select with `getElementById` or other function to map html nodes, but the window object don't has this method, if your reference is the window object you can use innerWidth and innerHeight, in this case I see that your canvas size is `40%` of the viewport then you can use `window.innerHeight * 0.40`.

I hope it helps you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>threejs - basic</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0; 
   overflow: hidden; 

  }

  canvas{
   display: inline-block;
   background: red;
   width: 40%;
   height: 40%;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>


<canvas id="myCanvas">
         <p>hi</p>
</canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.js"></script>

<script >
 var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');


 //Renderer 
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: myCanvas, antialias: true});
 renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * 0.40, window.innerHeight * 0.40);



 //Camera
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, ( window.innerWidth * 0.40) / ( window.innerHeight * 0.40 ), .01, 3000);
 //Scene
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();

 //Lights
 var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
 scene.add(light); 

 var light2= new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
 scene.add(light2);

   var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100);



 //Geometry Material 

 var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xF3FFE2});
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 mesh.position.z = -1000;

 scene.add(mesh);

//RenderLoop
 render();
 var delta = 0;
 function render(){
 //RotateMeshes
  mesh.rotation.x += .0001
  mesh.rotation.y += .001
  mesh.rotation.z += .001
 //ActiveVertices
  delta += 0.1;
  geometry.vertices[0].x = -25 + Math.sin(delta) * 50;
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

 };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```